# how to show html input fields in update panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

i am very new to Asp.Net.
I have Dashboard on the left side that contains different buttons and have update Panel on the right side.
**i have a seperate page (i.e index.aspx) which contains some Html input tags.**

What i want is to **show **index.aspx** in the Update Panel** whenever i click on(any one) button i.e **(Messages)** from the dashboard.

This highlighted area will be filled by updatepanel.
PS: Correct me if i am wrong because i am new in Asp.Net, Thanks
[image]

Comment: Sounds like you need a master page

Comment: @DenisWessels can you brief me about that?

Answer (score 0):

1.In Visual Studio right click on your project > Add > New Item > Web Forms Master Page.

Add the side menu to the master page.And all the child pages will be loaded inside the `ContentPlaceHolder control:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <table style="width: 100%;" border="1">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 30%;">
                    <a href="Default.aspx">Home</a><br />
                    <a href="Meetings.aspx">Meetings</a><br />
                    <a href="Messages.aspx">Messages</a><br />
                </td>
                <td style="width: 70%;">
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

2.Now right click the project in Visual Studio again > Add > New Item > Web Form with Master Page

When adding the new page you will be asked to select the master page, choose the master page created in step one.